# Redirect loops in Bing holding my sites back

Tags: htaccess, regex

Have been running HTTPS for a while and everything is good. I was looking at the webmaster tools on Bing and it shows some redirect loops going on. I see thousands of them.

I've looked at all the usual suspects but can't seem to find an explanation. I've checked the apache page http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/http-headers-tool/. No luck. Same thing with the Bing SEO tab. It gives me errors that don't show on the actual website.

One of the sites I'm talking about is https://thekingrepairs.com

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED:** Even though I had resolved those issues, it wasn't giving me an updated report. All of the data it was displaying was the old, though it still won't refresh or update to the current. I've confirmed through two separate sources and they both say it's okay.